# How print PDF with hyperLink

Tags: livecode

I try to print PDF with HyperLink, without succes

I have a lock field "etat" with data

Data are formatted like:

Code TAB Nom TAB Adress TAB Ville
56 Eric rue caboteur ST NAZAIRE
87 Franc rue Midin ST brevin
etc

the textStyle of item 3 "Adress" set to "Link and linktext set to ""http://maps.google.fr/maps?f=q&hl=fr&q=theadresse""

When i click on hyperlink item in field "etat" that work fine

Now i would like have the same result after printing this field in PDF

I use this code for printing

```
on mouseUp
  local theResult,thepDF
  ask file "" with type "PDF file|pdf|PDF "
  if it = "" then
    exit mouseUp
  end if

  put it into thePDF

  put the htmltext of fld "etat" into theResult

  --set the fileType to "revoPDF "
  open printing to pdf thePDF
    revPrintField the name of field "etat"
    --revPrintText theResult,"<%pageNumber%> of <%numPages%>","<%pageNumber%> of   <%numPages%>",the long id of field "etat" of stack "CDH"
  close printing

end mouseUp
```

I have a nice PDF with clicked words, but the click don't launch google maps

The dictionary say for command "print link"

"When printing fields, any text that has its linkText property set together with the link textStyle is treated as if a print link command had been executed with the contents of the property as link, and the formattedRect of the text as rectangle."

But no work.... I have a big headache

Thank for yours help to achieve this

Eric

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to understand your problem and reading through your code, I think maybe the link text…

```
"http://maps.google.fr/maps?f=q&hl=fr&q=theadresse"
```

should be…

```
"http://maps.google.fr/maps?f=q&hl=fr&q=" & theadresse
```

This is assuming theadresse is a variable containing a valid address to search in Google.

Comment: the first links works. However it is a good idea to test if the problem is on the URL generation in the PDF or with the particular URL. I would try a simple URL first.